# Creating a database project with Visual Studio - can't find database after running?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio, ef-database-first

I am following this tutorial (http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/setting-up-database) in order to create a database-first app with Entity Framework.

I hit "Run" and everything seems to be working, but in the next part of the tutorial (https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application), when I try to add a connection, it's not in the drop-down menu in the "Connection Properties" box under "Select or enter a database name".

Which server is the database on? I didn't specify anything about the server when I created the project for the first tutorial, and I figured that it would be on the default LocalDB that comes with Visual Studio (server name: (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB), but the database isn't there. Any ideas where I should look or what to try?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `.` (a dot) as Server Name?

Comment: This is the same as `localhost`, I used to connect to my database like this back in the old days. Also make sure `sqlserver` service/process is running. Make sure there already is a database in your SQL Server.

Comment: This gives me a message that "The server was not found or was not accessible".

Comment: How do I make sure sqlserver process is running (what do you mean by that)? And it's my understanding that the SQL solution creates the database (it'll create one named ContosoUniversityData in the example), is that not the case?

Comment: you should directly add the information in web.config : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Open your Web.config file and check your `<connectionStrings>` this is where the data source of the database will be. As shown:

[image]

However, which version of SQL Server do you have? As this can determine what the correct connection string will be.

Hit <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. And run the following:

%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances

You may have multiple instances, it would be worth checking each one. So it would be:
(localdb)(name of instance)

This article may also be of use to you:
http://rajchel.pl/2015/10/solving-connection-issue-with-sql-server-2014-localdb/

Comment: To clarify, can you add a _web.config_ file to a SQL Server Database Project? It doesn't come out of the box with one. I tried adding _web.config_ containing the following code to the project:
`<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
`
and hit "Start" again, but the database still doesn't show up in the server.

Comment: I have the 2014 version. The connection string you suggested looks right to me.

Comment: I would suggest doing the following. It's how I would usually create a database for this kind of application.

In the Solution Explorer, right-click the 'Controllers' folder, hit Add and then Add Controller.

A dialog will appear asking you to add a controller. Choose one of your models of which creates the data you want to store. Then for 'Data Context Class' click the plus(+) icon - it will suggest you a name for your database - I usually accept the generated one - so just hit 'OK'. Click 'Add'. The controller will be created. Then run the program and the database will also be created.

Answer (score 0):

What could be the case is that you have to run the application you created, and then do something to touch the database like creating / registering a user. After registration you can find the database on the specified location in your web.config settings. This was the solution in my case.